# Newton's equal and opposite force law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, newtonian-gravity

Is the equal and opposite force of Newton's third law caused by electromagnetic force or by the mass between the objects?

I was given the explanation that if I am standing on an edge of a cliff, it is the electromagnetic force between myself and the cliff that holds me from falling. Some term that as normal force. Standing on a scale measures normal force, not gravity etc.

(To my understanding mass does not cause force but warps spacetime and electromagnetic force is pretty strong force).

Answer (score 1):

For a person standing barefoot on a cliff, there are two things to note.  The atoms and molecules of the person's feet all have electrons "orbiting" around the nuclei of those atoms and molecules.  The same is true of the atoms and molecules that comprise the cliff.  Because like charges repel, the atoms and molecules of the feet and the cliff can approach each other only so far before the repulsive force between their respective electrons becomes great enough to support the weight of the person.  Due to this, Newton's third law is seen to be a consequence of electromagnetic repulsion between like charges.

Comment: So if I grab a rope with a hook at its end and pull myself up to that cliff, the cliff wouldn't repel the hook, nor will the rope or the hook at the end of the rope repel me? Plus it helps me to go opposite of spacetime, backward trajectory or what am I missing.

Comment: Some may find this silly inquiries or argumentative,. semantics and the like,  but since I can't read their mind.. what can I do.  furthermore F=ma is spacetime curvature propagation...? (i.e. gravitational waves) colliding? if two of them are head on.   Then again they shouldn't collide but repel if it gets too close... can't tell. Electromagnetic force is much stronger and besides so called gravity is the one constant and the absolute in all references and effects and is not relative in whatever context is implied by that.  It seems two different discription of reality is head to head...

Comment: Mass warps spacetime and momentum warps....? and acceleration warps...?  I am all over the map now.

Comment: @Ali, in my opinion, you are looking for things that aren't there.  Momentum and acceleration do not warp anything, as far as our current understanding of physics goes.